# unexpected non-void return value in void function Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3

Iam trying to return the response body from the switch statment in ECPLogin but it give me this error "unexpected non-void return value in void" even though i declare the function gotourl() -> String  in line 33. Please advice.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import SwiftECP
import XCGLogger
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var UsernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func _Login(_ sender: Any) {
         self.gotourl()
//        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotowelcome", sender: self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func gotourl() -> String{
        let username: String = UsernameField.text!
        let password: String = passwordField.text!
        let protectedURL = URL(
            string: "https://itsapps.odu.edu/auth/getInfo.p"
            )!
        let logger = XCGLogger()
        logger.setup(level: .debug)

        ECPLogin(
            protectedURL: protectedURL,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            logger: logger
            ).start { event in
                switch event {

                case let .value( body) :
                    // If the request was successful, the protected resource will
                    // be available in 'body'. Make sure to implement a mechanism to
                    // detect authorization timeouts.

                    print("Response body: \(body)")
                    return body


                    // The Shibboleth auth cookie is now stored in the sharedHTTPCookieStorage.
                    // Attach this cookie to subsequent requests to protected resources.
                    // You can access the cookie with the following code:
                    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
                        let shibCookie = cookies.filter { (cookie: HTTPCookie) in
                            cookie.name.range(of: "shibsession") != nil
                            }[0]
                        print(shibCookie)
                    }

                case let .failed(error):
                    // This is an AnyError that wraps the error thrown.
                    // This can help diagnose problems with your SP, your IdP, or even this library :)

                    switch error.cause {
                    case let ecpError as ECPError:
                        // Error with ECP
                        // User-friendly error message
                        print(ecpError.userMessage)

                        // Technical/debug error message
                        print(ecpError.description)
                    case let alamofireRACError as AlamofireRACError:
                        // Error with the networking layer
                        print(alamofireRACError.description)
                    default:
                        print("Unknown error!")
                        print(error)

                    }

                default:
                    break



                }
        }

    }

}
```

This part where i want to return

```
case let .value( body) :
                    // If the request was successful, the protected resource will
                    // be available in 'body'. Make sure to implement a mechanism to
                    // detect authorization timeouts.

                    print("Response body: \(body)")
                    return body
```

So is there a way around it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

That `return` isn't returning from `gotourl()`. It's returning from the closure you passed to `ECPLogin`. From your code and the error message it appears that the method you call takes a completion closure as its last argument, and this closure is not expected to return a value (that is, it returns `Void`). That's why you get the error-- you're returning a string when this closure is supposed to return nothing. It looks like the `ECPLogin` function you're using is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't produce a result immediately but instead does some work and calls the closure when it's done.

Your code doesn't return anything from `gotourl()`, which will be another problem, related to this.

How to fix it depends on how your app needs to work. Some options include:

- Change `gotourl()` so that it takes a completion closure instead of returning a value. Then replace your `return` with a lint that calls this closure.
- Use something like a dispatch group to make your code wait until the `ECPLogin` call completes, and return a value that way.
- Use some other option so that you don't need to wait until the string is available, like posting a notification.

Comment: Thanks for responding, iam trying to do a completion closure but i am new it and cant do it probably . would you mind if give example based on above code? thanks

Comment: What i want to achieve is to get the return page from ECPlogin.